# Error using ethers.utils.Interface

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js

Hi I am getting this error cannot figure out issue would appreciate if someone could see where I am going wrong.

> ERROR : invalid fragment object (argument="value", value={"name":"Transfer","topicHex":"0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","inputs":[{"name":"from","type":"address","internalType":"address","indexed":true,"_id":"632b1a337f6f7b1db8e18b5f","components":[]},{"name":"to","type":"address","internalType":"address","indexed":true,"_id":"632b1a337f6f7b1db8e18b60","components":[]},{"name":"value","type":"uint256","internalType":"uint256","indexed":false,"_id":"632b1a337f6f7b1db8e18b61","components":[]}]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)
> err: {
> "type": "Error",
> "message": "invalid fragment object (argument="value", value={"name":"Transfer","topicHex":"0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","inputs":[{"name":"from","type":"address","internalType":"address","indexed":true,"_id":"632b1a337f6f7b1db8e18b5f","components":[]},{"name":"to","type":"address","internalType":"address","indexed":true,"_id":"632b1a337f6f7b1db8e18b60","components":[]},{"name":"value","type":"uint256","internalType":"uint256","indexed":false,"_id":"632b1a337f6f7b1db8e18b61","components":[]}]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)",
> "stack":
> Error: invalid fragment object (argument="value", value={"name":"Transfer","topicHex":"0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","inputs":[{"name":"from","type":"address","internalType":"address","indexed":true,"_id":"632b1a337f6f7b1db8e18b5f","components":[]},{"name":"to","type":"address","internalType":"address","indexed":true,"_id":"632b1a337f6f7b1db8e18b60","components":[]},{"name":"value","type":"uint256","internalType":"uint256","indexed":false,"_id":"632b1a337f6f7b1db8e18b61","components":[]}]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)
> at Logger.makeError (/app/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
> at Logger.throwError (/app/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)

Receiving error when I call this function

```
new ethers.utils.Interface([ABI]);
```

where ABI is a javascript object

```
const ABI = {
            anonymous: false,
            inputs: [
                {
                    indexed: true,
                    internalType: 'address',
                    name: 'operator',
                    type: 'address'
                },
                {
                    indexed: true,
                    internalType: 'address',
                    name: 'from',
                    type: 'address'
                },
                {
                    indexed: true,
                    internalType: 'address',
                    name: 'to',
                    type: 'address'
                },
                {
                    indexed: false,
                    internalType: 'uint256[]',
                    name: 'ids',
                    type: 'uint256[]'
                },
                {
                    indexed: false,
                    internalType: 'uint256[]',
                    name: 'values',
                    type: 'uint256[]'
                }
            ],
            name: 'TransferBatch',
            type: 'event'
        }
```

Comment: Weird. It works alright for me. What version of `ethersjs` are you using? I'm using `^5.6.9`.

Comment: Really weird, after going through documentation still haven't figured it out. Using ^5.7.0